# AWS Lambda get access denied when accessing DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I configured my AWS stack using AWS CloudFormation as follow

```yaml
Resources: 
    DynamoDBTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - 
            AttributeName: "PK"
            AttributeType: "S"
          - 
            AttributeName: "SK"
            AttributeType: "S"
          - 
            AttributeName: "GSI1_PK"
            AttributeType: "S"
          - 
            AttributeName: "GSI2_PK"
            AttributeType: "S"
          - 
            AttributeName: "GSI1_SK"
            AttributeType: "S"
          - 
            AttributeName: "GSI2_SK"
            AttributeType: "S"
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: "PK"
            KeyType: "HASH"
          -
            AttributeName: "SK"
            KeyType: "RANGE"
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          -
            IndexName: "line_tickets"
            KeySchema:
              -
                AttributeName: "GSI1_PK"
                KeyType: "HASH"
              -
                AttributeName: "GSI1_SK"
                KeyType: "RANGE"
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: "ALL"
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 5
              WriteCapacityUnits: 5
          -
            IndexName: "users_tickets"
            KeySchema:
              -
                AttributeName: "GSI2_PK"
                KeyType: "HASH"
              -
                AttributeName: "GSI2_SK"
                KeyType: "RANGE"
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: "ALL"
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 5
              WriteCapacityUnits: 5
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 5
          WriteCapacityUnits: 5
        TableName: !Ref TableName
        Tags:
            - Key: ENV
              Value: !Ref ENVName
      DependsOn:
        - "LambdaExecutionRole"
    GetAccountLambdaFun:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
      Properties:
        FunctionName: GetAccountLambdaFun
        Description: Retrive account From DB.
        Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
        Handler: index.handler
        MemorySize: 128
        Runtime: !Ref LambdaRuntime
        Environment:
          Variables:
            DB_END_POINT: !Ref LambdaDBEndPoint
            TABLE_NAME: !Ref TableName
            DB_API_VERSION: !Ref LambdaDBApiVersion
            DB_AWS_REGION: !Ref "AWS::Region"
        Code:
           S3Bucket: !Ref LambdaHostS3BucketName
           S3Key: !Sub 
            - "${Folder}/account-get-lambda-fun.zip"
            - Folder: !Ref  ENVName
        Tags:
          - Key: ENV
            Value: !Ref ENVName
      DependsOn:
        - "DynamoDBTable"

    LambdaExecutionRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties: 
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: 
                - 'sts:AssumeRole'
        RoleName: **LambdaExecutionRole**
        Path: /
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - !Ref LambdaLogGroupPolicy
          - !Ref DynamoFullAccessPolicy
    LambdaLogGroupPolicy:
      Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
      Properties:
        Description: Lambda log groupt policy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
              Resource: !Sub arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
              Resource: !Sub arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*
    DynamoFullAccessPolicy:
      Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
      Properties:
        Description:dynamo full access policy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Sid: "DynamoDBIndexAndStreamAccess"
              Action:
                - 'dynamodb:GetShardIterator'
                - 'dynamodb:Scan'
                - 'dynamodb:Query'
                - 'dynamodb:DescribeStream'
                - 'dynamodb:GetRecords'
                - 'dynamodb:ListStream'
              Resource:
                - !Sub
                  - arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/*/index/*
                  - tableName: !Ref TableName
                - !Sub 
                  - arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/*/stream/*
                  - tableName: !Ref TableName
            - Effect: Allow
              Sid: "DynamoDBTableAccess"
              Action:
                - dynamodb:BatchGetItem'
                - dynamodb:BatchWriteItem'
                - dynamodb:ConditionCheckItem'
                - dynamodb:PutItem'
                - dynamodb:DescribeTable'
                - dynamodb:DeleteItem'
                - dynamodb:GetItem'
                - dynamodb:Scan'
                - dynamodb:Query'
                - dynamodb:UpdateIte'
              Resource:
               - !Sub 
                  - arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/*
                  - tableName: !Ref TableName
            - Effect: Allow
              Sid: "DynamoDBDescribeLimitsAccess"
              Action: 'dynamodb:DescribeLimits'
              Resource:
               - !Sub
                  - arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/*
                  - tableName: !Ref TableName
               - !Sub 
                  - arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/*/index/*
                  - tableName: !Ref TableName
```

when i try to test the lambda function via AWS console i get an error:

> ERROR DynamoDB GET REQUEST failed AccessDeniedException: User:
> arn:aws:sts::XXXX:assumed-role/LambdaExecutionRole/GetAccountLambdaFun
> is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource:
> arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:XXXX:table/TableName

I am not sure why is that as i configure a **DynamoFullAccessPolicy** that should grant the lambda access to this DB.

Comment: Your CloudFormation template appears to have a lot of unnecessary quotes and some unmatched quotes, for example: `dynamodb:BatchGetItem'`. Fix at least the unmatched quotes. Personally, I'd remove all quotes that aren't necessary. This is YAML, not JSON.

Comment: The !Sub syntax you have is incorrect. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html. Check the created role in IAM Console to see, if it has been generated correctly.

Comment: Seems like your Sub is wrong. Best to do is look in the IAM to see what policy is created actually. You can post the policy and Lambda function code, to see what action you are actually trying to do.